# How to customize a new ERGM term of calculating geographical distance between two nodes using R?

Tags: r, geocoding, network-analysis, statnet

Nodes are universities around the world. I'm doing ERGM (Exponential random graph models) using R about what factors affect universities to have collaborations. I have node attribute including both longitude and latitude information. I would like to use the information of geo-locations to test if the distance between universities (nodes) will affect the probability of collaboration. I am aware that I should make new ERGM terms, but I don't have a clue of doing.

The starting code is something like the following:

```
library(statnet)    
model<-ergm(g ~ edges +  gwesp(0.2, fixed=T), 
             control=control.ergm(parallel=np, parallel.type="PSOCK"))
```

Comment: It sounds like you haven't converted long/lat to distance yet. You need to do that first. Then include the distance metric in your model, for which I believe you want `nodecov('distance')`. But please check the `ergm.terms` in the [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ergm/ergm.pdf) to be sure.

Comment: Is it not edgecov(network)?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, which is why I suggested you check `ergm.terms`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried an answer for this question, with a reproducible example.
I`m not sure if this is correct! So comments (correct/ improvments/ etc.) are welcome.

In the question it was asked for a geometry column. For simplicity I sperate those for lon lat columns.

```
library(cshapes)
library(sf)
library(statnet)
library(dplyr)


#load a shapefile
country <- cshp(date = as.Date("2019-01-01"), useGW = TRUE, dependencies = TRUE)


#create random nodes within
set.seed(452)
sf_use_s2(FALSE)

points <- data.frame(ID = 1:20,
                     geometry = st_sample(country, size = 20, type = "random")) %>% st_as_sf()

#prepare those: creating lon/lat values and transform to dataframe 
points <- points %>% mutate(ID = as.character(ID),
                            lon = sf::st_coordinates(.)[,1],
                            lat = sf::st_coordinates(.)[,2]) %>% 
                         select(ID, lon, lat, geometry) %>% as.data.frame()


#create edges between those points
edges <- data.frame(from = c("1","3","5", "12"),
                    to = c("3", "20", "9", "15"))

##create a network 
net <- as.network(edges, vertices = points, directed = FALSE, multiple = FALSE)

#example run ergm
ergm(net ~edges)

#extract the lon, lat columns of the network
geos <- data.frame(lon = get.vertex.attribute(net, "lon"),
                      lat = get.vertex.attribute(net, "lat")) %>% st_as_sf(., coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)

#transform to a crs given in Meters
geosm <- geos %>%  st_transform(32732) 

#calcluating the distances between eacht node
dist_matrix <- as.data.frame(st_distance(geosm, geosm))

#rename
names(dist_matrix) <- geos$ID
rownames(dist_matrix) <- geos$ID
dist_matrix <- as.matrix(dist_matrix)


#run the ergm with the new variable 
ergm(net ~edges +edgecov(dist_matrix))
```